# C UDP socket not working

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm having a problem with one of my homework assignments on socket programming in C.. we're doing a simple client/server thing with UDP and I'm having trouble with the server.. here's a snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[PACKET_DATA_LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
```

Originally the `sockfd = socket(AF_NET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)` was a `SOCK_STREAM`, but since the project specification was to do it in UDP and not TCP I changed `STREAM` to `DGRAM`.

I call the server like: `./receiver 1234`

And I get the error: `ERROR on accept: Operation not supported on socket`

However, if I change it back from `DGRAM` to `STREAM` it compiles and `./receiver 1234` works fine.

Help?

Thanks!
-kstruct

*EDIT*
This is what error() looks like (this is pre-given code, I did not write it, it came as part of the project)

```
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

*EDIT2*
Here's more of my code (what follows immediately after the first block of code I posted).. I guess the boilerplate code does call accept(), but shouldn't that trigger a different output message? Namely, shouldn't it say `ERROR opening socket` rather than `ERROR on accept`?

```
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
      error("ERROR on binding");
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR on accept");
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that you get the message `ERROR on accept: ...` but then in *EDIT2* you say that you get `ERROR opening socket` but you would expect `ERROR on accept`. That's what you told us you got.

Comment: My bad, other way around, I'll fix that.
*EDIT* Fixed. I've looked through the rest of my code and there is no other accept() calls in the code.

Comment: It's not valid to call `accept()` on a datagram socket. Why would you expect to get an error opening the socket, if you haven't called `accept()` yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UDP is connectionless. Why would you be calling `accept`?

Comment: I never called accept explicitly.. it must be a side-effect of doing `sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`, but I have the same call in my client and there is no error...

Comment: Hrm, you better paste more code then. Does `error()` wind up calling `perror(3)` to give you good diagnostics?

Comment: Posted more of my code.. it does call accept() apparently (came with the project template)

Comment: Excellent. Had your code checked the error return of `listen()`, it probably would have found the error three lines sooner. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`accept(2)` does not make sense for a connectionless datagram protocol such as UDP. `accept(2)` is only for `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET` protocols.

You *can* `connect(2)` a UDP protocol to ask the kernel to provide more filtering but this is not always desirable.